# How to compare column values in two files using shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to check if 6th column of two files output1.dat and output2.dat are identical. How do I do that?

Comment: are your two files containing same number of lines?

Comment: There are several ways to determine that.  What did you try?

Comment: That is a job for AWK. I suggest you look into a tutorial like [this one](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~dholland/computers/awk.html).

Comment: the number of lines in both are same. I just started learning shell, but I need to do this one urgently. How would I go about doing it with awk?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use awk for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$6;next}a[FNR]!=$6{print "diff @ lineNr:",FNR;exit}' file1 file2
```

didn't test, I hope it works for your needs. I assume the col/field separator in your files is space.

if two files are same on 6th col, no output. otherwise print the first non-equal line number.